# how to display data in a single view from multiple tables in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

**Emp_table**

```
Sno Name Salary Country
 1  XXXX  XXXX    101
 2  XXXX  XXXX    102
```

**Country Table**

```
CID   CountryName
101      IND
102      USA
```

**OutPUt**

```
Sno  Name Salary Country
 1   XXXX  XXXX    IND
 2   XXXX  XXXX    USA
```

Comment: How about defining a *View Model* that holds data from multiple tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
 select e.Sno,  e.Name, e.Salary, c.Country
 from Emp_table e,Country c
 where e.Country = c.CID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name{ get; set; }

  public string Salary{ get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeCountry
{
   public Employee employeeObj{ get; set; }
   public Country countryObj{ get; set; }
}
```

and in your View:

```
 @model namespace.EmployeeCountry
```

and you can get use it as:

```
 @Model.employeeObj.Name
 @Model.countryObj.CountryName
```

Comment: public Addresses addressObj{ get; set; } //is it class where declare

Comment: showing error Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sorry: that replace Addresses class with Employee, it was typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the country name from db when you query for employee list.
This is the model class.

```
public class Employee {
    public int Sno { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    public int  CountryId { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to fill the list of above model from data source. I'm assuming that you're using MS-SQL. In order to interact with DB you need something like below in your DAL layer.

```
public DataTable GetSPDataTable(string spName){
 DataTable retVal = new DataTable();
string _connectionString ="Enter your connection string here";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = spName;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        adp.Fill(retVal);
 }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        ex = e;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
}
}
return retVal;
    }
```

Now at create an stored procedure named "getEmployeeData" in your DB

```
SELECT E.*,C.CountryName FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN Country C
ON E.Country = C.CID
```

Now everything else is ready, you just need to call the DAL function from your controller's action, pass it sp name "getEmployeeData" and set connection string.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
  DataTable dt;
dt = this.GetSPDataTable("getEmployeeData");
List<EmployeeModel> list = new List<EmployeeModel>();
            list = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                    select new EmployeeModel
                    {
                        Sno= Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sno"]),
                        Name= dr["Name"].ToString(),
                        Salary= dr["Salary"].ToString(),
                        CountryId= Convert.ToInt32(dr["CountryId"]),                       
                        CountryName= Convert.ToInt32("CountryName")

                    }).ToList<EmployeeModel>();

Return View(list);
}
```

Since you'll be using list of Employee as model on your view, you can declare your model at view as per following

```
@model List<Employee>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>sno</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>salary</th>
  <th>country</th>
</tr>

foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
  <td>@item.Sno</td>
  <td>@item.Name</td>
  <td>@item.Salary</td>
  <td>@item.CountryName</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you., but Query where we declare in model or controller ?

Comment: Showing Error                                                                                         An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_dmz4but5.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: added the details, hope you get the idea.